# How many workers per supervisor?

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, beam

Is there a boundary for how many workers a specific supervisor process should supervise? I've kept coming back to this question a couple of times while building an OTP supervision tree regarding the performance & fault-tolerance:

Should a single supervisor process supervise **all** workers (thousands) of the same, specific domain, or should you put a smaller number of supervision processes (under that main supervisor) which supervise a subset of worker processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no boundary or limit for the number of children a supervisor can manage. This is limited only by the system limits on max number of processes. It should also be considered that a supervisor does not do any active management by itself. Unless it is asked to do something, all it does is to sit and wait for `exit` messages from its children.

The question should a single supervisor manage all workers, or should they be divided among some number of child supervisors is more an architectural one. If all workers are of the same type and `one_for_one` or `simple_one_for_one` strategy is used, a single supervisor managing workers directly is the best solution. If requirements are more complicated, it may be useful to group workers of the same type in a child supervisor, to e.g. implement some special restart strategy.